# php function that returns a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a really simple function:

```
function experience_query($id) {
$sql = @mysql_query(
"
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $id
");
return("$sql");
}
```

When I call this function:

```
$q = categories_query("1001"); 
while( $list = mysql_fetch_assoc($q) )
{
extract($list);
echo $name;
}
```

I am getting an error" "mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource..."

Am I allowed to return mysql queries from a function?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace this:

```
return("$sql");
```

With this:

```
return $sql;
```

By surrounding `$sql` in quotes you are returning the string representation of the MySQL resource.