# mysql_fetch_array()/mysql_fetch_assoc()/mysql_fetch_row()/mysql_num_rows etc... expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to select data from a MySQL table, but I get one of the following error messages:

> mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

This is my code:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName LIKE $username');

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['FirstName'];
}
```

Comment: you can get more useful eroor msg using::  QUERY or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Also the obligatory note: **Your code is prone to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection).** You should validate and/or escape the user input. Have a look at [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). **Never trust user data.**

Comment: Actually, the OP's code will cause a syntax error on the MySQL server, but at least it is _not_ vulnerable to SQL Injection because single quotes doesn't have variable interpolation.

Comment: @FelixKling I realize this is very old, and likely the most accurate possible at the time, but your comment is now dangerously wrong in one way: `mysql_real_escape_string` is not the be-all and end-all of SQL injection protection; it's still vulnerable to a number of attacks. (No, you never said it's perfect, but you implied it was the only required solution) The best solution now is PDO, as far as I know.

Comment: @NicHartley To add on your comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) are descriptions on how that would work.

Comment: Gah. Extending this question to include MySQLi and PDO was a bad idea. They each have their own slightly different syntax and error messages and they could perfectly well have had their own questions. Combining everything into one giant three-part question just makes this less Googleable and forces people who arrive here to wade through irrelevant content to get to what they want. It's also invalidated a great many of the answers below, and makes this question "Too Broad" by the standards we normally apply. It's a mess, in my opinion, but it's too late to fix now.

Comment: Besides the first error, what you posted would have thrown another error, this for `LIKE $username` since we're more than likely dealing with a string here and not an integer. Therefore it would require it to be quoted.

Comment: For anyone coming here who is using MySQLi: Please see this post instead: [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Answer (score 681, accepted):

A query may fail for various reasons in which case both the mysql_* and the mysqli extension will return `false` from their respective query functions/methods. You need to test for that error condition and handle it accordingly.

**[mysql_ extension](http://docs.php.net/book.mysql)**:

> **NOTE** The [mysql_ functions are deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) and have been removed in php version 7.

Check `$result` before passing it to `mysql_fetch_array`. You'll find that it's `false` because the query failed. See the [`mysql_query`][1] documentation for possible return values and suggestions for how to deal with them.

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = $_POST['password'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName LIKE '$username'");

if($result === FALSE) { 
    trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['FirstName'];
}
```

Comment: Right, but using a die() if the query fails is a little to much.

Comment: I was going to design an entire error handling mechanism for the OP, but decided that might be beyond the scope of my answer.

Comment: @scompt.com Yes it's also covered in several other answers.  I guess I was just making the point that since this is the _accepted_ answer on a high visibility question, in addition to the (excellent) advice about how to properly catch errors in future, it should (IMHO) actually answer the specific question (ie explain _why_ there's an error in this case).

Comment: Instead of `if($result === FALSE)` you can use `if(! $result)`. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: mysql_query(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli

Answer (score 164):

This error message is displayed when you have an error in your query which caused it to fail. It will manifest itself when using:

- `mysql_fetch_array`/`mysqli_fetch_array()`
- `mysql_fetch_assoc()`/`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`
- `mysql_num_rows()`/`mysqli_num_rows()`

**Note**: This error does *not* appear if no rows are affected by your query. Only a query with an invalid syntax will generate this error.

**Troubleshooting Steps**

- Make sure you have your development server configured to display all errors. You can do this by placing this at the top of your files or in your config file: [`error_reporting(-1);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php). If you have any syntax errors this will point them out to you.
- Use [`mysql_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php). `mysql_error()` will report any errors MySQL encountered while performing your query.

Sample usage:

```
    mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysql_select_db($db_name) or die("cannot select DB");
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if (false === $result) {
        echo mysql_error();
    }
```

- Run your query from the MySQL command line or a tool like [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php). If you have a syntax error in your query this will tell you what it is.
- Make sure your quotes are correct. A missing quote around the query or a value can cause a query to fail.
- Make sure you are escaping your values. Quotes in your query can cause a query to fail (and also leave you  open to SQL injections). Use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to escape your input.
- Make sure you are not mixing `mysqli_*` and `mysql_*` functions. They are not the same thing and cannot be used together. (If you're going to choose one or the other stick with `mysqli_*`. See below for why.)

**Other tips**

`mysql_*` functions should not be used for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799).  Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help to choose. If you care to learn, here is [good PDO tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Given this question today http://stackoverflow.com/q/43804651/1415724 and other similar ones lately; I think it may be worthwhile to update your answer to contain something like *"That error can also be caused by not executing the query with `mysql_query()` / `mysqli_query($connection)` etc."*; thoughts? Since no other answers in this Q&A mentions this.

Answer (score 113):

Error occurred here was due to the use of single quotes (`'`). You can put your query like this:

```
mysql_query("
SELECT * FROM Users 
WHERE UserName 
LIKE '".mysql_real_escape_string ($username)."'
");
```

It's using `mysql_real_escape_string` for prevention of SQL injection. 
Though we should use MySQLi or PDO_MYSQL extension for upgraded version of PHP (PHP 5.5.0 and later), but for older versions `mysql_real_escape_string` will do the trick.

Comment: Why adding noise with string concatenation instead of just putting the variable in the query string?

Comment: @Matteo Riva
Yeah, but I thought this is little cleaner way to separate variables from string. :)

Answer (score 58):

As [*scompt.com* explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2973209/1438393), the query might fail. Use this code the get the error of the query or the correct result:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$result = mysql_query("
SELECT * FROM Users 
WHERE UserName LIKE '".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."'
");

if($result)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $row['FirstName'];
    }
} else {
    echo 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    echo 'Whole query: ' . $query; 
}
```

See the [documentation for `mysql_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) for further information.

The actual error was the single quotes so that the variable `$username` was not parsed. But you should really use `mysql_real_escape_string($username)` to avoid SQL injections.

Answer (score 51):

Put quotes around `$username`. String values, as opposed to numeric values, must be enclosed in quotes.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName LIKE '$username'");
```

Also, there is no point in using the `LIKE` condition if you're not using wildcards: if you need an exact match use `=` instead of `LIKE`.

Comment: And what if $username is: "   '; DROP TABLES;" ?  That is the advantage to using prepared statements and bound values, which I think the asker would like to retain.

Answer (score 41):

Please check once the database selected are not because some times database is not selected

Check

```
mysql_select_db('database name ')or DIE('Database name is not available!');
```

before MySQL query
and then go to next step

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName LIKE $username');

f($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 40):

Your code should be something like this

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName LIKE '$username'";
echo $query;
$result = mysql_query($query);

if($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error("error message for the user")); 
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['FirstName'];
}
```

Once done with that, you would get the query printed on the screen. Try this query on your server and see if it produces the desired results. Most of the times the error is in the query. Rest of the code is correct.

Comment: Do not use this code.  It is wide open to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 33):

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName LIKE $username');
```

You define the string using single quotes and PHP does not parse single quote delimited strings. In order to obtain variable interpolation you will need to use double quotes OR string concatenation (or a combination there of). See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php for more information.

Also you should check that mysql_query returned a valid result resource, otherwise fetch_*, num_rows, etc will not work on the result as is not a result! IE:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName LIKE $username');

if( $result === FALSE ) {
   trigger_error('Query failed returning error: '. mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
} else {
   while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
      echo $row['username'];
   }
}
```

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php for more information.

Comment: Do not use this code, even if you add quotes.  It is wide open to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 32):

This query should work:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName LIKE '%$username%'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['FirstName'];
}
```

The problem is single quotes, thus your query fails and returns FALSE and your WHILE loop can't execute. Using % allows you to match any results containing your string (such as SomeText-$username-SomeText).

This is simply an answer to your question, you should implement stuff  mentioned in the other posts: error handling, use escape strings (users can type anything into the field, and you MUST make sure it is not arbitrary code), use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead mysql_connect which is now depricated.

Answer (score 27):

If you tried everything here, and it does not work, you might want to check your MySQL database collation. Mine was set to to a Swedish collation. Then I changed it to `utf8_general_ci` and everything just clicked into gear.

Answer (score 27):

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName LIKE '%$username%'") or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['FirstName'];
}
```

Sometimes suppressing the query as `@mysql_query(your query);`

Comment: Do not use this code.  It is wide open to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 24):

Try this, it must be work, otherwise you need to print the error to specify your problem

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * from Users WHERE UserName LIKE '$username'";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['FirstName'];
}
```

Comment: 1) Wide open to SQL injection, 2) does not include error handling which is causing the error in OP's case.

Comment: +1.  @deceze Yes it is wide open.  But no more so that the OP's or the accepted answerer's code ;-)  And it's not the lack of error _handling_ in the OP's code causing the error... it's _the error_, and this answer at least attempts to resolve that (by putting single quotes around the string literal in the `LIKE` expression).

Comment: +1 Please add a space between LIKE and '$username', rest appears to be fine except the SQL injection. Why not use = instead of LIKE operator username must be exactly matched

Answer (score 24):

```
$query = "SELECT Name,Mobile,Website,Rating FROM grand_table order by 4";

while( $data = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo("<tr><td>$data[0]</td><td>$data[1]</td><td>$data[2]</td><td>$data[3]</td></tr>");      
}
```

Instead of using a WHERE query, you can use this ORDER BY query. It's far better than this for use of a query.

I have done this query and am getting no errors like parameter or boolean.

Comment: Remember to use `htmlspecialchars()` when using arbitrary data in the context of HTML.  Otherwise, you risk creating valid HTML when reserved characters are used in the data.

Answer (score 20):

There might be two reasons:

1. Have you opened the connection to the database prior to calling mysql_query function? I don't see that in your code. Use mysql_connect before making the query. See `php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php`
2. The variable **$username** is used inside a single quote string, so its value will not be evaluated inside the query. The query will definitely fail.

Thirdly, the structure of query is prone to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You may use prepared statements to avoid this security threat.

Answer (score 19):

Try the following code. It may work fine.

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName ='$username'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['FirstName'];
}
```

Comment: This code is subject to SQL injection and should not be used.

Answer (score 15):

Go to your `config.php`. I had the same problem. Verify the username and the password, and also sql select is the same name as the config.

Answer (score 14):

Include a connection string variable before the MySQL query. For example, `$connt` in this code:

```
$results = mysql_query($connt, "SELECT * FROM users");
```

Comment: This doesn't address the issues in the question. It's also wrong and would raise another error.

Answer (score 14):

Don't use the depricated mysql_* function (depricated in php 5.5 will be removed in php 7). and you can make this with [mysqli](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp) or [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

here is the complete select query

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // code here 
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Your post does not deal with the problems addressed by the question, which are an invalid query and incuficient error reporting. This post is off topic.

Answer (score 13):

```
<?php
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName LIKE '".$username."'");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $row['FirstName'];
    }
?>
```

And if there is a user with a unique user name, you can use "=" for that. There is no need to like.

Your query will be:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName ='".$username."'");
```

Comment: This code is wide open to SQL injection and should not be used.

Comment: @AnujGarg This code takes direct input and concatenates it into the query.  Someone could write their own SQL in the post data for `username` and it will be executed.

Comment: So what to use to prevent the code from SQL injection?

Answer (score 11):

Try This

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$result = mysqli_query('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName LIKE $username');

if($result){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['FirstName'];
}
}
```

Comment: @panjehra mysql_* is depricated now  and will removed from php 7 . Use mysqli_* instead

Answer (score 11):

Any time you get the...

> *"Warning: mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given"*

...it is likely because there is an issue with your query. The `prepare()` or `query()` might return `FALSE` (a Boolean), but this generic failure message doesn't leave you much in the way of clues. How do you find out what is wrong with your query? You *ask*!

First of all, make sure error reporting is turned on and visible: add these two lines to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

If your error reporting has been set in the php.ini you won't have to worry about this. Just make sure you handle errors gracefully and never reveal the true cause of any issues to your users. Revealing the true cause to the public can be a gold engraved invitation for those wanting to harm your sites and servers. If you do not want to send errors to the browser you can always monitor your web server error logs. Log locations will vary from server to server e.g., on Ubuntu the error log is typically located at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. If you're examining error logs in a Linux environment you can use `tail -f /path/to/log` in a console window to see errors as they occur in real-time....or as you make them.

Once you're squared away on standard error reporting adding error checking on your database connection and queries will give you much more detail about the problems going on. Have a look at this example where the column name is incorrect. First, the code which returns the generic fatal error message:

```
$sql = "SELECT `foo` FROM `weird_words` WHERE `definition` = ?";
$query = $mysqli->prepare($sql)); // assuming $mysqli is the connection
$query->bind_param('s', $definition);
$query->execute();
```

The error is generic and not very helpful to you in solving what is going on.

With a couple of more lines of code you can get very detailed information which you can use to solve the issue *immediately*. Check the `prepare()` statement for truthiness and if it is good you can proceed on to binding and executing.

```
$sql = "SELECT `foo` FROM `weird_words` WHERE `definition` = ?";
if($query = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) { // assuming $mysqli is the connection
    $query->bind_param('s', $definition);
    $query->execute();
    // any additional code you need would go here.
} else {
    $error = $mysqli->errno . ' ' . $mysqli->error; // 1054 Unknown column 'foo' in 'field list'
    // handle error
}
```

If something is wrong you can spit out an error message which takes you directly to the issue. In this case, there is no `foo` column in the table, solving the problem is trivial.

If you choose, you can include this checking in a function or class and extend it by handling the errors gracefully as mentioned previously.

Comment: How can you write "Just make sure you handle errors gracefully and never reveal the true cause of any issues to your users." and `echo $error;` in one post?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @PaulSpiegel. It has been a while since I wrote or revisited the answer and had missed that I had left the echo in there.

Answer (score 10):

```
<?php
      $username = $_POST['username'];
       $password = $_POST['password'];

     $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName LIKE '".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."'")or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
 echo $row['FirstName'];
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 8):

First, check your connection to the database. Is it connected successfully or not?

If it's done, then after that I have written this code, and it works well:

```
if (isset($_GET['q1mrks']) && isset($_GET['marks']) && isset($_GET['qt1'])) {
    $Q1mrks = $_GET['q1mrks'];
    $marks = $_GET['marks'];
    $qt1 = $_GET['qt1'];

    $qtype_qry = mysql_query("
        SELECT *
        FROM s_questiontypes
        WHERE quetype_id = '$qt1'
    ");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qtype_qry);
    $qcode = $row['quetype_code'];

    $sq_qry = "
        SELECT *
        FROM s_question
        WHERE quetype_code = '$qcode'
        ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $Q1mrks
    ";
    $sq_qry = mysql_query("
        SELECT *
        FROM s_question
        WHERE quetype_code = '$qcode'
        LIMIT $Q1mrks
    ");
    while ($qrow = mysql_fetch_array($sq_qry)) {
        $qm = $qrow['marks'] . "<br />";
        $total += $qm . "<br />";
    }
    echo $total . "/" . $marks;
}
```

Comment: Do not use this code.  It is wide open to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 8):

> Make Sure You're Not Closing Database By using db_close() Before To
>   Running Your Query:

If you're using multiple queries in a script even you're including other pages which contains queries or database connection, then it might be possible that at any place you use db_close() that would close your database connection so make sure you're not doing this mistake in your scripts.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't have any MySQL Error appearing while checking, make sure that you properly created your database table. This happened to me. Look for any unwanted commas or quotes.

Answer (score 5):

Check your connection first.

Then if you want to fetch the exact value from the database then you should write:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName =`$usernam`");
```

Or you want to fetch the `LIKE` type of value then you should write:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName LIKE '%$username%'");
```

Comment: This code is wide open to SQL injection and should not be used.

Answer (score 5):

You can also check  wether `$result` is failing like so, before executing the fetch array

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName LIKE $username');
if(!$result)
{
     echo "error executing query: "+mysql_error(); 
}else{
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
       {
         echo $row['FirstName'];
       }
}
```

Comment: Do not use this code.  It is wide open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: But if the code works, I feel you should edit the code and input the needed filters instead of castigating the code.

Comment: Simple usage of filters will not fix what is wrong with this code.  The best solution is to use prepared/parameterized queries with PDO or similar.  I don't see any point in fixing it, as the correct answer has already been posted here.  Ideally, this answer will be deleted.  However, you are welcome to fix your answer and I will happily up-vote it if it is correct.

Comment: Well, if you feel the answer isn't worth considering you can go ahead and get read of it. However, I thought the whole point of this community is to share and contribute knowledge. If you have something to share instead of showing and putting people off.

Comment: You are correct, the whole point of this community is to share knowledge.  That's why added explanation with my downvote, and further explained why your filter suggestion was not sufficient.  I'd much prefer to alert you, along with anyone else who finds your answer, that the code above is insecure.  It's better for everyone to learn the correct methods rather than perpetuating bad code.  And, I cannot delete your answer, nor would I.  That's up to you, if you choose to do so.

Answer (score 3):

Usually an error occurs when your database conectivity fails, so be sure to connect your database or to include the database file.

```
include_once(db_connetc.php');
```

OR

```
// Create a connection
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());

//Select database
mysql_select_db("db_name", $connection) or die(mysql_error());

$employee_query = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE `id` ='".$_POST['id']."'";

$employee_data = mysql_query($employee_query);

if (mysql_num_rows($employee_data) > 0) {

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($employee_data)){
        echo $row['emp_name'];
    } // end of while loop
} // end of if
```

- Best practice is to run the query in sqlyog and then copy it into your page code.
- Always store your query in a variable and then echo that variable. Then pass to `mysql_query($query_variable);`.

Comment: 1) You don't know if I have or have not voted on any answer here, up or down. 2) As I explained in my first comment; your answer doesn't reference the problem (*boolean passed to mysql_fetch_array*) and you have syntax errors

Comment: You have incorrect quotes in both your code examples. The syntax highlighting applied to your second code block is a dead give-away that something is wrong

Comment: This code is subject to SQL injection and should not be used.  @EngrZardari if you are using this code on your production systems, you have undoubtedly been hacked and should remedy the situation buy using prepared/parameterized queries with PDO or similar.  There are bots that have automated testing for such vulnerabilities.

Comment: @EngrZardari About your *"there is no any error, i have pasted here code which i currently using."* [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-mysql-fetch-assoc-mysql-fetch-row-mysql-num-rows-etc#comment32012558_21249122) above. There was a missing quote in the query which I corrected. That would have thrown a (PHP) parse error.

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally PHP has been tolerant to bad practice and failures in code,
which makes debugging quite hard.
The problem in this specific case is that both *mysqli* and *PDO*
by default don't tell you, when a query failed and just return `FALSE`.
(I will not talk about the depricated *mysql* extention.
The support for *prepared statements* is reason anough to switch either to *PDO* or *mysqli*.)
But you can change the default behavior of PHP to always throw *exceptions* when a query fails.

For *PDO*: Use `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", "test","");
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$result = $pdo->query('select emal from users');
$data = $result->fetchAll();
```

This will show you the following:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'emal' in 'field list'' in E:\htdocs\test\mysql_errors\pdo.php on line 8
>
> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'emal' in 'field list' in E:\htdocs\test\mysql_errors\pdo.php on line 8

As you see, it tells you exactly, what is wrong with the query, and where to fix it in your code.

Without `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`
you will get

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean in E:\htdocs\test\mysql_errors\pdo.php on line 9

For *mysqli*: Use `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'test', '', 'test');

$result = $mysqli->query('select emal from users');
$data = $result->fetch_all();
```

You will get

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'Unknown column 'emal' in 'field list'' in E:\htdocs\test\mysql_errors\mysqli.php on line 8
>
> mysqli_sql_exception: Unknown column 'emal' in 'field list' in E:\htdocs\test\mysql_errors\mysqli.php on line 8

Without `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` you only get

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_all() on boolean in E:\htdocs\test\mysql_errors\mysqli.php on line 10

Of course, you could manually check the MySQL errors.
But I would go crazy if I had to do that every time I made a typo -
or worse - every time I want to query the database.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it work fine

assign the post  variable to the variable

```
   $username = $_POST['uname'];

   $password = $_POST['pass'];

  $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM userData WHERE UserName LIKE $username');

if(!empty($result)){

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo $row['FirstName'];
     }
}
```

Comment: This code is subject to SQL injection attacks and should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

since $username is a php variable we need to pass it as string to mysqli so since in the query u started with a single quote we will use the double quote, single quote and a fullstop for the concatination purposes ("'.$username.'") if you started  with a double quote you would then reverse the quotes ('".$username."').

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName LIKE "'.$username.'"');

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
      echo $row['FirstName'];
     }

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName LIKE '".$username."' ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
      echo $row['FirstName'];
     }
```

but use of Mysql has depreciated much, use PDO instead.it is simple but very secure

Comment: But Mysql use has depreciated. you can use PDO instead. Let me give you a sample login.

Comment: Passwords should NEVER EVER be stored in plain text form, make use of the built in fucntions that PHP has for dealing with the hashing of passwords and the verifying of hashed passwords!

Comment: Do not use this code. It is wide open to SQL injection attacks.